# UITableView array returns nil

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray, ios

Right now I have a tableview, and I can assure you that the delegate method all work. But I am trying to load the tableview from an array. the same array returns actual objects when i log then earlier in the app, but when I try to access the same array in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
it always returns nil/null.Here is the implementation of `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`:

```
NSLog(@"cell for row at twitter called");
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSDictionary *tweet = [timeLineData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// NSLog(@"Tweet at index %d is %@", [indexPath row], tweet);
//NSLog(@"Tweet: %@", tweet);
cell.textLabel.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tweet valueForKeyPath:@"user.name"];


return cell;
```

I am so confused as to why this is, because in all of my other projects the same code works just fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Virindh Borra

Comment: When you load the tableview, is your `NSLog` statement called? What is the code inside your `numberOfRowsInSection` method?

Comment: Its indeed called, and in numberofrowrsinsection it returns 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it help if you access the array using:

```
[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
```

Comment: thats what I am doing but it returns nil.

Comment: can you post the implementation of the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method? It would help us give you a better answer.

Comment: Sorry, there is nothing i can find wrong with the code you posted (the problem may lie elsewhere).  The only advice i have with the information given is that the table view cells might be initialized before timeLineData is initialized.